# Как сделать РЕГИСТРОЗАВИСИМОЕ сравнение слов?

Tags: java

пример тестового текста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему слова, которые начинаются с большой буквы при сравнении пропускает и не считает одинаковыми не могу понять?

Проблему нашел - длина первых слов после разделителей на один больше чем слово. Что там за символ присутствует непонятно. И почему он не дает выполнить условие equals непонятно.

Если меняю input.split("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я\n]+") на input.split("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я]+") то проблема уходит, но как тогда запомнить где были разделители строк и расставить их по прежним местам?

```
    String[] words = input.split("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я\\n]+");
    String[] duplicates = new String[words.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++) {
            if(words[i].contains("\n")) {
                break;
            }
            if(words[i].equals(words[j])){
                duplicates[i] = words[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: а если `equals` заменить на `equalsIgnoreCase`?

Comment: нужно чтобы сравнение было с учетом регистра

Comment: тогда каждую стрингу разбивайте на `char[]` и проверяйте каждый `char`

Comment: input какие строки содержит?

Comment: This is a test
And this is also a test
And these are also tests
test
Это тест
Это также тест
И это также тесты

Comment: Только при вводе утеряны разделители строк, они вместо пробелов должны быть перед словами начинающимимся с Большой  буквы

Comment: @Al159, а какая задача у вас? Найти дубликаты и положить их в список? Или подсчитать количество слов-дубликатов? И при этом регистр имеет значение, правильно?

Comment: Найти дубликаты и добавить к каждому из них в начале символ, и вернуть отредактированную строку. Регистр имеет значение.

Comment: Что с чем нужно сравнивать вообще?

Comment: Слова друг с другом в строке. Строка состоит из нескольких строк. То есть, имеются разделители строк. Словом считается последовательность только букв. Кириллица или латинский.

Answer (score 0):

Вам вместо  метода `equals` нужно использовать `equalsIgnoreCase`

Comment: пробовал - но рабоатет это только для случаев, когда одно слово начинается с Большой а другое с маленькой, а елси оба с Большой то не считает почему-то одинаковыми. И к тому же необходимо именно с учетом регистра сравнение.

Comment: тогда нужно писать в вопросе РЕГИСТРОЗАВИСИМОЕ сравнение слов

Comment: Это уже не я отредактировал а модераторы

Comment: Изменил название вопроса

Comment: @Al159 попробуйте вот эту регулярку для разбивки слов `content.split("\\s+|;|\\n")`

Comment: добавил изображение с тестовым текстом